# Why doesn't isAppearanceLightStatusBars affect on Status bar content color programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, statusbar, android-theme

I've tried to change the color of status bar content using **isAppearanceLightStatusBars**:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        val controller = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView)
        controller?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
}
```

it doesn't change anything, but when i change it in theme xml file, it works normal:

```xml
<style name="Theme.NutShop" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
</style>
```

I need to know the reason of this problem, and solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, **ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView)** is returning null, so i changed it with **WindowCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window, window.decorView)** then it worked now, but still don't know why the first one is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

First you have add the below items to your base theme. Also note that your base theme name is added to your manifests application tag.

`<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/black</item>`

`<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>`

android:statusBarColor -> represents the color of your status bar

android:windowLightStatusBar -> represents the color of the icons and text on your status bar.

- True means that your status bar color is a light color so make the text and icons dark in color.
- False means that yyour status bar color is a dark color so make the text and icons light in color.